# Source code location in Android NativeActivity based project

Tags: android, android-ndk

Is there any way to relocate my source code (including all .h .cpp and .mk files) outside of project folder? In other words, i want to move out content of jni folder out of android project folder. Now, physical structure of my project looks like this:

```
.../ProjectFolder/AndroidProjectFolder/jni/(sources and make files)
.../ProjectFolder/AndroidProjectFolder/(other android project files)
.../ProjectFolder/iosProjectFolder/(other ios project files)
```

I want to make like this:

```
.../ProjectFolder/src/(sources and make files)
.../ProjectFolder/AndroidProjectFolder/(other android project files)
.../ProjectFolder/iosProjectFolder/(other ios project files)
```

Is there any correct way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.  I use the directory above jni for instance MyProject/src/ This sample builds a shared library...You can also build static libraries.  Notice the $(call my-dir)/.. the 'call my-dir)' points to the jni directory that contains the Android.mk file.  So adding the /.. backs it up a directory.

```
LOCAL_PATH  := $(call my-dir)/..

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

FILE_LIST := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/*.cpp)

ifdef DEBUG
CONFIG_DIR  := Debug
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -Werror -Wno-psabi -O0 -ggdb -D_DEBUG
LOCAL_CXXFLAGS    := -Werror -Wno-psabi -O0 -ggdb -D_DEBUG -fexceptions
LOCAL_LINK_FLAGS    := -ggdb
else
CONFIG_DIR  := Release
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -Werror -Wno-psabi -O2 -DNDEBUG
LOCAL_CXXFLAGS  := -Werror -Wno-psabi -O2 -DNDEBUG -fexceptions
endif

LOCAL_MODULE    := MyProject
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
LOCAL_LDFLAGS   := $(LOCAL_LINK_FLAGS)
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -lGLESv2 -landroid -llog -lGLESv1_CM -lEGL

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Thank you! But source files won't be visible in eclipse if i'll move them out of project directory (i mean IDE, not comoiler)?

Comment: just need to move the eclipse project up to the Project folder or make another project in the source directory and include multiple projects in your workspace to see it in eclipse.  I'm not particularly fond of eclipse forcing workspaces to be directory based either.